# Using linq to retrieve differences between two lists with duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists which contain only duplicates I got from different sources.

```
//Duplicate 1
var Duplicate1 = list1.GroupBy(d => new { d.Name, d.Value })
    .Where(dup => dup.Count() > 1).SelectMany(dup => dup);
```

This returns: `{{red, red}, {red, red}, {green, green}, {green, green}}`

```
//Duplicate 2
var Duplicate2 = list2.GroupBy(d => new { d.Name, d.Value })
    .Where(dup => dup.Count() > 1).SelectMany(dup => dup);
```

This returns: `{{red, red}, {red, red}, {green, green}, {green, green}, {green, green}}`

How can I using linq to sort through these lists so that all I have is the difference which would be `{green, green}`?

Comment: Not sure the suggested link applies, it looks like you might have multiple duplicates with the same values, if you need all of them to be able, for example, to count them, then Intersect would not help (equality would collapse those duplicates). What do you need in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create two lookups, then join these lookups, check which lookup pair has the most items, and then take a number of items equal to the difference:

```
var al = Duplicate1.ToLookup(x => x);
var bl = Duplicate2.ToLookup(x => x);

var result = al.Join(bl,  agrp        => agrp.Key, 
                                bgrp  => bgrp.Key,
                         (agrp, bgrp) => agrp.Count() > bgrp.Count() ?
                                         agrp.Take(agrp.Count() - bgrp.Count()) :
                                         bgrp.Take(bgrp.Count() - agrp.Count()))
                .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: This is the solution I went with, but I also figured out what my route problem was, These comparisons being made where under the assumption everything was the exact same, The issue was caused by the list being stored in two different places of memory so I had to override the equals and GetHashCode for the objects so that it was referring to the name and value being the same and not the places in memory.

Comment: @RichardMc That's exactly the kind of issue I was referring to in my comment to the question. Equality can be tricky depending on what kind of objects you are dealing with.